# Unexpected output instead of runtime error

Tags: c++

It might be obvious for who knows the background magic, but I could not understand how below code is giving correct output. I expected a runtime error. Please help.

```
class a
{
  public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Hello\n"<<endl;
        int d = 100;
        cout<<d<<endl;
    }

    int val;
};


int main()
{
   a* ptr;

   ptr->print();

   return SUCCESS;
}
```

OUTPUT is as below :

```
Hello

100
```

Comment: Because **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no magic - your code has **undefined behavior**. In your code you do not access `ptr` which is implicitly passed to `print()` as `this` pointer, that is why no error happen.

It may happen in several other cases:

- Accessing fields of `a` instance. It will require to read memory `*(this + field_offset)` which will cause runtime error.
- Accessing virtual methods. Implementations known to me use *vtable* to do that, which is usually stored as first pointer in object space, so pointer to *vtable*  would be same as this, so: `vtable = *this`
- Other cases, depending on compiler and platform

NOTE: type conversion is omitted from examples with `this`

Answer (score 4):

`a::print` is a not a virtual method, hence it is just a normal function that has an extra argument to receive the `this` pointer. Since the method never uses the `this` pointer, the fact that it is uninitialized doesn't turn into a memory access error or other failure. Declaring `a::print` `static` will still compile in this case since it doesn't use the `this` pointer. Declaring `a::print` `virtual` or accessing `this` inside the method will likely lead to the program crashing, at least under some circumstances.

The behavior is still undefined and it is an ill-formed program, but as it stands now it is very likely to work deterministically on most systems. In general C++ does not give runtime errors for such cases, but if you compile with e.g. "clang++ -Wall" a warning indicating the uninitialized variable will be given. (And there are tools such as clang's asan which will go further in diagnosing such errors.)